# Table does fit to the page in twocolumn article but push the below part out of margin

Tags: floats, two-column

[image]

```
\documentclass[article]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\soulregister\cite7
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{todo}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{nidanfloat}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}
{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{Figures/}}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{dblfloatfix}

\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\modulolinenumbers[5]


%\renewcommand{\thefootnote}
\newcommand\degrees[1]{\ensuremath{#1^\circ}}

\newcommand\mycaption[1]{\caption{\footnotesize{#1}}}

\newcommand\myfootnote[1]{\footnote{\small{#1}}}

\newcommand\scalemath[2]{\scalebox{#1}{\mbox{\ensuremath{\displaystyle #2}}}}

\setlist[enumerate]{label*=\arabic*.}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn

\section{Introduction}\label{sec:intro}

Due to the increasing demand of energy throughout the world during the past decades as well as the pollution provided by conventional energy resources, e.g. oil and coal, it is essential to develop renewable and clean energy resources. Solar energy as an eternal and promising energy source, which has a great potential 

\subsubsection{Mesh generation}

ANSYS, ICxy conventional energy resources, e.g. oil and coal, it is essential to develop renewable and clean eney conventional energy resources, e.g. oil and coal, it is essential to develop renewable and clean eney conventional energy resources, e.g. oil and coal, it is essential to develop renewable and clean enexxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxximney portion and collective cover.
It is worth noting that the mesh independent study was done to obtain high quality mesh which rexxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxy conventional energy resources, e.g. oil and coal, it is essential to develop renewable and clean enexxxxy conventional energy resources, e.g. oil and coal, it is essential to develop renewable and clean enexxxxxxy conventional energy resources, e.g. oil and coal, it is essential to develop renewable and clean enexxrtserysdgD hexahedral mesfhsfgfds satisfies the aforementioned condition.
\begin{table*}[t]
\vspace{\baselineskip}
\centering 
\caption{ Paramfaaaaaavaluafserimental daffffffffffata and Numerical result}
    \small
    \setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}
    \setcellgapes{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccc}
\hline
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{10 AM} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{12 PM} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2 PM} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{4 PM} \\ \hline
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$I_{e}$ = 746.15 $W/m^{2}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$I_{e}$ = 843sgsggg0 $W/m^{2}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$I_{e}$ = 741.80 $W/m^{2}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$I_{e}$ =  $W/m^{2}$} \\
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$q''$ = $W/m^{2}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$q''$ = 247.99 $W/m^{2}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$q''$ = 218.09 $W/m^{2}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$q''$ = 131.44$W/m^{2}$} \\ \hline
  &  V$_{out}$ &      P    &    V$_{out}$   &          P   & V$_{out}$    &         P        &       V$_{out}$    & P \\ \hline
Experimental &          &       &          &     sdgsdg  &    afafd   &    26.28      &       5.91      &     fafafsa   \\
 Numerical &     6.82      &    24.76    &      8.44       &     33.51     &     6.97      &        236.20 &   6.73        &     15.30     \\ \hline
Error (\%)  &  2.29        &     5.78    &    5.27        &  4sgsgds    &      0.14       &   0.30        &  13.87         &      12.67
\end{tabular}
\label{Table 5}
\end{table*}
\subsubsection{ Validation }

The Manzanarecccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccche numericaly conventional energy resources, e.g. oil and coal, it is essential to develop renewable and clean enezy conventional energy resources, e.g. oil and coal, it is essential to develop renewable and clean eney conventional energy resources, e.g. oil and coal, it is essential to develop renewable and clean ene was shdgssssssn Table \ref{Table 5}.

zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz

\subsection{  }


\begin{comment}

\end{comment}

%Fig. a shows how the path lines (in red and blue) fill the sample domain area and follow the orientation vectors (black arrows) from the LSC solution. Fig. \ref{fig6}b is an image of the bottom layer of a sample 3D printed with short carbon fiber filled filament from the path lines shown in 

\section{Results and discussion}

\section{Conclusions}

Following are thesdgggggggggggggggggggggggggggarks for this staaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaay:

\begin{itemize}
  \item One entry in the list
  \item Another entry in the list
\end{itemize}

Future study will be designing a differsdgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggdddnvestigate an experggggggggggggggggggggggggggstudy.

\section*{Acknowledgement}
The authors would like to acknowledsdgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggges to the instituggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggid flow maggggggggggggggggggggggggggr their provided facilities.

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you showed a complete small example that showed the problem your question would be more understandable. As it is no one can really help. `[H]`  can not make tables spanning the page columns. I assume by `[*table]`  you mean `\begin{table*}` but if you do not show what you did it is hard to tell you why it did not work as you expect.

Comment: Man, it is not possible to attach the code here

Comment: In order to show the problem I need to attach long file which is not possible here

Comment: No need for a long file. The `\begin{table*} ... \end{table*}` plus a page of text using the `lipsum` package all wrapped up in `\documentclass...   \end{document}`.

Comment: @Turkan no, you can make a small one or  two page example with just the minimal text required to show the problem. If you just show syntax like `[*table]` which presumably is not in your document at all and give vague description of the problem such as "the sentences in botttom of the page goes out of margin" then how do you expect anyone can help you?. Floats do not normally force an over-full page so if that is happening there is something wrong on your page, but if you give no indication of what you did it will be impossible to help.

Comment: Yep I understand your comments. The issue is the problem is appeared when I put the code at least one page for you to see what I meant by go out of margin. I am trying to do that

Comment: I added a picture about what I meant by the out of margin. My table is above this page actually and as you see some portions of my conclusion is lower than page number. It is not correctly set between two columns

Comment: \begin{table*}[t]
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccc}
\hline
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{M} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\ \hline
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{}$ = 75 $W/m^{2}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$q''$ = 144$W/m^{2}$} \\ \hline
  &  V$_{out}$ & && &   &   &  & \\ \hline
Experimental &&  & &  & & &   & \\
 Numerical &  && &  &       &&&  \\ \hline
Error (\%)  &  &  &  &&&   &  &    
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

Comment: The table code you posted will result in orror messages upon trying to compile it. `\multicolumn{2}{c}{}$ = 75 $W/m^{2}$} ` contains an extra `$` and an extra `}`.

Comment: please add the code to the question where you can mark it as a code block so lines preserved, code in comments does not format well as you see. But also the example should be something we can run to see the problem. But as leandriis says the code has an error. after _any_ error the pdf is not intended to be usable, just a debugging aid, so it may quite possibly have bad page breaks.

Comment: (i) Table code doesn't help. If  someone insert it in a test document, it not reproduce your problem (read @DavidCarlisle comments), (ii) from table code is not clear why you like to have table over two columns, (iii) let repeat me other comments: for help you we need complete small document beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. BTW, `table*` in normal circumstances (whe are not taken special action) is always on the top of the next page from point of it insertion in document. SO, your question is unclear and consequently I suggest to close it as such.

Comment: The problem is not the table it is the bad page break.You need to show an example that produces the overlapping text otherwise it is impossible to guess. Something is stopping the page breaking at that point but you have given  information what. It is highly unlikely to be related to the tabular that you have shown. If you replace that by `\begin{table*}\vspace{7\baselineskip}\end{table*}` (or a suitable space that takes up  the space of the table, does the page still over-print?

Comment: how can I put the code here when there is limitation? I should put complete code that you can see my problem!!

Comment: Are you aware that the code you posted results in an error message? After getting an error message, do not look at the output but fix the error first. The error message " Command \c@dblbotnumber already defined." seems to be caused by the combination of `dblfloatfix` and `nidanfloat`.

Comment: No error go to overleaf and run it

Comment: Look. Please do not make it complicated. The code works well and I uploaded the photo above. If anybody knows please help me

Comment: The code you posted throws errors on Overleaf with all TeX Live versions I tried (2020, 2019, 2018, 2017, 2016). You can see the number of errors/warnings that are reported in the little red symbol next to the "Recompile" button. The fact that Overleaf produces output does not mean that there were no errors. Indeed you cannot rely on the output being useful if there are errors. If I remove the package that causes the error message (`\usepackage{dblfloatfix}`), the file compiles without errors. ...

Comment: ...  Some text still runs into the margins, but that appears to be only because those are not actual words, so TeX cannot hyphenate them properly. If you replace `enexxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxximney` and friends by normal words that can be hyphenated, you should not have any problems

Comment: Thanks moewe But the problem is not due to that. I checked in my file with correct words. The problem below the page is important actually. BTW why there is not error in my overleaf and just warning!!?

Comment: The only warnings I got were regarding the overfull \hbox bla bla.

Comment: I get some weird effects if `\usepackage{dblfloatfix}` is loaded, but once I remove `\usepackage{dblfloatfix}` from the preamble, the only issues I can see in your MWE are related to line breaking of words that are not real words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your document example is not compilable. please fix it.
- Do you really need all those package, which you load in your document preamble (some of them twice, with recent `latex` installation some of them you not need to load). Please cleanup and reorganise document preamble.
- Your document use some "exotic" packages which make your troubles. remove them!

A possible solution for your document is:

```
\documentclass[article]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{soul}
\soulregister\cite7
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathtools}% supercede  amsmath
\usepackage{breqn}    % dont use it!
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{sectsty}
%\usepackage{float}     % do you really need it?
\usepackage{stfloats}   % new, for placement figure*, table* on the same page where are inserted
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{todo}
%\usepackage{nidanfloat}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{Figures/}}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{caption, subcaption}
%\newcommand\mycaption[1]{\caption{\footnotesize{#1}}}
\usepackage{multicol}

%\usepackage{dblfloatfix}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\setlist[enumerate]{label*=\arabic*.} this is default setting
\usepackage{lineno}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand\degrees[1]{\ensuremath{#1^\circ}} % better to use siunitx: \si{degree}

\newcommand\myfootnote[1]{\footnote{\small{#1}}}
\newcommand\scalemath[2]{\scalebox{#1}{\mbox{\ensuremath{\displaystyle #2}}}}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn

\section{Introduction}\label{sec:intro}
\lipsum[1]

\subsubsection{Mesh generation}
\lipsum[2]
    \begin{table*}[b]
\centering
\caption{Redesigned table by use of the \texttt{siunitx} package}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}
    \setcellgapes{3pt}
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{8}{S[table-format=3.2]} @{}}
    \hline
    &\mcc[2]{1} &\mcc[2]{1} &\mcc[2]{}  &\mcc[2]{}                          \\
    \hline
    & \mcc[2]{$I_{e} = \SI{7415}{W/m^2}$} 
                    & \mcc[2]{$I_{e} = \SI{83}{W/m^2}$} 
                                    & \mcc[2]{$I_{e} = \SI{410}{W}$} 
                                                    & \mcc[2]{$I_{e} = \si{W/m^2}$}         \\
    & \mcc[2]{$q'' = \si{W/m^2}$} 
                    & \mcc[2]{$q'' = \SI{249}{W/m^2}$} 
                                    & \mcc[2]{$q'' = \SI{29}{W/m^2}$} 
                                                    & \mcc[2]{$q'' = \SI{131.44}{W/m^2}$}   \\
    \hline
    & {$\mathrm{V_{out}}$} 
            &  P    & {$\mathrm{V_{out}}$}
                            & P     & {$\mathrm{V_{out}}$}
                                            &  P        & {$\mathrm{V_{out}}$}
                                                                    & P     \\ 
    \hline
Experimental 
    &       &       &       &  1.23 &  4.56 &    26.28  &   5.91    & 21.09 \\
 Numerical 
    & 6.82  & 246 & 8.& 1 &  7 &     &   6.73    & 150 \\ 
    \hline
Error (\%)  
    &  2. &   &  7 &  4.00 &  &  0.0     &  13    & 12.67
\end{tabular}
\label{Table 5}
    \end{table*}

\subsubsection{ Validation }
\lipsum[3-4]

\subsection{ ? }
\lipsum[5]

\begin{comment}
Fig. a shows how the path lines (in red and blue) fill the sample domain area and follow the orientation vectors (black arrows) from the LSC solution. Fig. \ref{fig6}b is an image of the bottom layer of a sample 3D printed with short carbon fiber filled filament from the path lines shown in
\end{comment}

\section{Results and discussion}
\lipsum[6]

\section{Conclusions}
\lipsum[7]
\begin{itemize}
  \item One entry in the list
  \item Another entry in the list
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[8]

\section*{Acknowledgement}
\lipsum[9]
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines shows page layout)

Comment: GREAT..............

Comment: The issue with this code is [H] does not work in front of table and it gives error

Comment: @Turkan, of course not works :- ) I comment loading `float` package and ask you, if you really need it. See code in my answer. Use of `H` specifier for float positioning can lead to undesired side effect, so better is to used `htb` instead or just `b` in my answer.

Comment: You are grear Zarko:)